# Getting stuck on ROS for Raspbian Jessie

Tags: ros, rostopic-echo, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following this tutorial on installing ROS Kinetic on Raspbian Jessie and I got stuck Building the Catkin Workspace.

/etc/dphys-swapfile has been configure to

```
CONF_SWAPFILE=/mnt/sda2/swap.file
CONF_SWAPSIZE=1024
```

/sda2 is a 1TB external Hard Disk. It does not have a file "swap.file" though. How should I create it?

`free -h`

now gives me

```
                  total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          859M       778M        81M        48M        84M       381M
-/+ buffers/cache:       312M       547M
Swap:         1.0G         0B       1.0G
```

Running
`sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/kinetic -j2`

causes me to get stuck and terminal shows

```
[100%] Building CXX object modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object modules/python2/CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265967/getting-stuck-on-ros-for-raspbian-jessie/) by [Alsing](https://answers.ros.org/users/28489/alsing/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-07-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-07-10**:
It can take hours to compile OpenCV and PCL. I recommend that you just let it run. Eventually it will finish or run out of memory and crash.

**Comment by [Alsing](https://answers.ros.org/users/28489/alsing/) on 2017-07-11**:
Hey! Thanks for the prompt reply! Did I do the swap correctly? I did not explicitly create a "swap.file" in sda2. What happens if memory runs out?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-07-11**:
I'm not sure how dphys-swapfile is supposed to work, but your output from `free -h` clearly shows 1GB of available swap space, so it's probably working.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-11**:
@Alsing: if you have the opportunity, I would really look into cross-compilation combined with distributed compilation. For the latter you could look into `distcc`. If you have any hosts available, building things like OpenCV and PCL will be much faster than just using the rpi alone.

**Comment by [Alsing](https://answers.ros.org/users/28489/alsing/) on 2017-07-11**:
@gvdhoorn Thanks for that suggestion! I might spend the same time figuring out the configuration. @Ahendrix gives a very good solution if only I wasn't stuck with an Eigen3 issue. I'll have to figure out that one for now.

**Comment by [Alsing](https://answers.ros.org/users/28489/alsing/) on 2017-07-18**:
@ahendrix What happens if it hangs? Should I reboot it or let it be?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-07-18**:
"hangs" is tricky. It may be working, it just may not show any obvious signs that it's working. I would open another terminal and use `top` or `htop` to monitor CPU activity to see if any process is using the CPU heavily, or if many small compile processes are running.

**Comment by [Alsing](https://answers.ros.org/users/28489/alsing/) on 2017-07-18**:
It would be completely unresponsive, no mouse or keyboard responses. Display wise, I'm stuck on the activity bar showing 99%. Then again, it could be the display not updating, but I really wouldn't know and can't test.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-07-18**:
That sounds pretty stuck. It might be swapping so much that it seems very slow, or may be completely locked up. If it's swapping it may eventually respond very slowly, and sometimes SSH may work better. If I didn't get any response after a minute I'd probably reboot and try to rebuild with `-j1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As long as you see compile activity, I would let it run. If it seems like it's stuck on a particular process or file, take note of the exact process and file name and check back in a few hours (or overnight) to see if it's still compiling the same file.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0